# The equation $x^2+y^2=0$ over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

Do we have a fast method for proving that the equation $x^2+y^2=0$ over $\mathbb{F}_{7}$ has one solution $(0,0)$ without testing all the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{7}$?

Comment: Try testing $x^2\operatorname{mod}7$ from $x=1$ to $3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This could help ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B11_and_the_first_supplement

Answer (score 3):

Yes, at least for prime fields – using *quadratic reciprocity*:

Indeed, if the equation $x^2+y^2=0$ has a solution such that $x,y\ne 0$, then $-1$ is a square in $\mathbf F_p$. Now, the *$1$st supplementary law* of quadratic reciprocity asserts that
$$\biggl(\frac{-1}{p}\biggr)=\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{p-1}2}, $$
and if $p=7$, this is equal to $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the general question suggested in the title, consider a finite field $\mathbb F_q$. Then:

$x^2+y^2=0$ has a nontrivial solution in $\mathbb F_q$
iff $z^2+1=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb F_q$
iff there is an element of order $4$ in $\mathbb F_q^\times$
iff $4$ divides $q-1$, since $\mathbb F_q^\times$ is cyclic.

Comment: The $q$ are those in https://oeis.org/A085759